# Value is not allowed for attribute xsi:type

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

EDIT 13/07/2020 :

What I'm trying to achieve is validate the 3 elements in the XML.
The DocumentId element will always contain a string, the ID element will always contain a string, and the element01 will always contain a string and have the attribute `xsi:type="ns11:creditNote"`.
The element Document and DocumentList can have any attributes from any namespaces.

The 3 elements to validate are :

- `/po:DocumentList/po:Document/po:DocumentId`
- `/po:DocumentList/po:Document/po:ID`
- `/po:DocumentList/po:Document/po:element01` with the attribute `xsi:type="ns11:creditNote"`

This is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<po:DocumentList xmlns:po="http://www.example.com/PO1" 
xmlns:ns11="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/PO1 Main.xsd" indexing="false" numPages="2" pageId="0" itemsPerPage="2" itemCount="3">
    <po:Document>
        <po:DocumentId>b6f066ea-1d48-566c-967a-f81a2d935d59</po:DocumentId>
        <po:ID>documents/b6f066ea-1d48-566c-967a-f81a2d935d59</po:ID>       
        <po:element01 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns11:creditNote">documents/b6f066ea-1d48-566c-967a-f81a2d935d59</po:element01>
    </po:Document>
</po:DocumentList>
```

I created a main XSD file (`Main.xsd`) for the namespace `http://www.example.com/PO1` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:po="http://www.example.com/PO1" xmlns:ns11="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/PO1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" schemaLocation="Main_Sub_1.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="DocumentList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Document">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="DocumentId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="element01" type="ns11:creditNote"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And I created another file `Main_Sub_1.xsd` for the namespace `urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns11="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <xs:simpleType name="creditNote">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

However when I try to validate the main XSD file I get this error :

**"'ns11:creditNote' must refer to an existing simple or complex type."**

I made some experiments, and tried changing the namespace `urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2` to "test01" and it works, but as soon as I use this specific urn, it throws an error.

I saw that the urn points to an xsd schema that can be viewed here :
https://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/oasis/ubl/2.0/?page=ubl-invoice-2_0_xsd.html

So I'm guessing the validator, when seeing this namespace, instead of importing my file with the type creditNote I created, looks at a file in a distant server which does not have the type creditNote defined. I don't have a lot of experience with XML and XSD but since replacing the urn with anything else makes my validation work, that's how I understood it.

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. Remove `xsi:type="ns11:creditNote"` from the XML or 2. Define the type `ns11:creditNote` somewhere.

Comment: @zx485 : How can I define the type ns11:creditnote ? I tried creating another xsd and importing it but I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Tried some things, too. But also couldn't provide a solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to validate 2 specific elements in my XML and allow any other attributes and elements that could be added.

You need to be very specific about *where* these additional tags/attributes need to appear. The best way to do that is to edit your question and add some example messages that show the extra content.

> when I try to validate the XML I have an error : "Value 'ns11:creditNote' is not allowed for attribute 'xsi:type'."

You are asserting that the tag 'po:DocumentList' matches a type definition with name `creditNote` in namespace `urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2`. But you have not defined that type. In fact you have not even imported an XSD which has that targetNamespace.

Were you really trying to override the type of po:DocumentList? Or were you trying to bring the 'creditNote' type into play for some other purpose?

In summary, your question suggests a certain amount of confusion about how to define and use XML Schema extension mechanisms. Happy to help if you clarify the question a bit.

Comment: I edited my question. I made some changes and tried to fix it but I'm still failing. I created another file to define the type creditNote within the namespace `urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2`. Can you check my edit to see if it clarifies my question ?

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I'm still not clear what you are trying to achieve though. Why use xsi:type when you have already declared the type of element01? Do you really want to allow optional attributes on all 3 tags? If so, do you want to allow literally _any_ attributes, or attributes from imported xsds _only_ or ...? Sorry to ask, but you need to explain these things, or else not mention requirements like 'regardless of their attributes'.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is validate the 3 elements in the XML. I don't know why the xsi:type is used in the xml file, this is the file I receive and I can't modify it.

Comment: The DocumentId element will always contain a string, the ID element will always contain a string, the element01 will always contain a string and have the attribute xsi:type="ns11:creditNote". The element Document and DocumentList can have any attributes from any namespaces. I will remove the unnecessary requirements.

Comment: If you don't know why the xsi:type is being used then you are _very_ unlikely to create a correct XSD. You need to understand the problem before looking for a solution. At the very least you should ask the team which supplied this XSD what the allowed variations are. The answer might surprise you.

Comment: btw, your XML validates OK for me, if I edit the schemaLocation attribute and add the namespace before the file path. But that's not the whole solution to your problem (see previous comment)

Comment: If I still have problem with the XSD I will try to fix it, but the reason why xsi:type is used is not what I'm looking for right now and isn't important to this specific problem. In fact, the XML and XSD files are much more complex than the example I provided, so I will most likely have other errors. I just tried the best as I could to create a basic example of the problem I'm facing with the import and namespace.

Comment: How exactly did you edit the schemaLocation ? Does your import element look like `<xs:import schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 Main_Sub_1.xsd" namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"/>`

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/PO1 http://www.example.com/PO1 Main.xsd"